# Flexbox stretch columns (or not)

Tags: css, flexbox

Using the "old" flexbox implementation, I would use `-webkit-box-align: start;` to stop side by side columns from being of equal length.

I can't figure out how to do this under the new spec - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_flexbox.

My main div is `<div role="main">` and it has two `<section class="app">` side by side within the div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new equivalent property to `box-align` is `align-items`, though you'll have to use `-webkit-align-items` for now. Set it to `flex-start` on the flexbox container of those two boxes to get rid of the equal-height stretching and align the two boxes at the top. Learn more at http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/#align-items-property.